# e possivel zipar arquivos com o php?

Tags: php, jquery

gostaria de saber se e possivel zipar fotos com o php, por exemplo: eu seleciono 300 fotos e essas 300 fotos ao clicar no botao elas serao zipadas e enviadas no e-mail. e possivel fazer isso com o php?

Comment: Sim é possível! tem uma extensão chamada zip.

Comment: to vendo aqui no manual do php nao esta dizendo que ele cria um zip

Comment: ah achei vlw cara

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, teria como postar como implementou em seu código a extensão mencionada pelo rray? Obrigado.

Comment: Já deu uma procurada no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.zip.php) ?

Comment: @David eu nem fiz ainda cara eu so queria saber se era possivel para estudar sobre, eu vou tentar implementar com e-mail minha ideia e zipar as fotos e mandar pro email do cara as fotos zipadas